# On the Use of Vstretch in a Minipage Environment

Tags: fontsize, minipage, displaystyle

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch of Letters
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textnormal{\scalefont{1.5}{\textbf{THIS IS A LONG SENTENCE IN A MINIPAGE ENVIRONMENT THAT IS DISPLAYED IN A DESIRABLE MANNER.}}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\vskip 35pt

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{But when I try to impose a vertical stretch of the letters, I get---}}

\vskip 5pt

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\vstretch{1.4}{\textnormal{\scalefont{1.5}{\textbf{THIS IS A LONG SENTENCE IN A MINIPAGE ENVIRONMENT THAT IS DISPLAYED IN A DESIRABLE MANNER.}}}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It produces the output:

[image]

QUESTION: Why after imposing the use of the `vstretch` command, the second sentence is not automatically broken apart and justified as it is in the first sentence; and, how may I make the display of the second sentence coincide with the first?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\scalebox` is like `\mbox` and produces a single line box. You need to nest the `minipage` if you really must do this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical Stretch of Letters
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textnormal{\scalefont{1.5}{\textbf{THIS IS A LONG SENTENCE IN A MINIPAGE ENVIRONMENT THAT IS DISPLAYED IN A DESIRABLE MANNER.}}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\vskip 35pt

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{But when I try to impose a vertical stretch of the letters, I get---}}

\vskip 5pt

\begin{center}
\vstretch{1.4}{\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textnormal{\scalefont{1.5}{\textbf{THIS IS A LONG SENTENCE IN A MINIPAGE ENVIRONMENT THAT IS DISPLAYED IN A DESIRABLE MANNER.}}}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I left in the scalefont but you don't really need it (or `\textnormal`) here. You are starting off at 12pt so if you want a font 150% bigger just select 18pt. similarly you don't need vstretch you could directly use `\scalebox{1}{1.4}{..}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It  works very nicely.